# How Can I Copy Data From an Access Table to An array In VBA?

Tags: arrays, ms-access, vba

I'm working on a program that can take data from one field in a table and put that whole column into an array or even just read from the table itself. The code seems to use a form or something else I would like to use an array.

Comment: Could you show an example of the code 'that gets close`?

Comment: An ADO recordset has a `GetRows` method which returns an array.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223369/how-to-select-1-field-from-database-then-store-to-array-in-vb6/16223888#16223888

Answer (score 8):

This will work:

```
Dim rstData    As DAO.Recordset
Dim v          As Variant

Set rstData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select FirstName from FaxBook3")
v = rstData.GetRows(rstData.RecordCount)
```

"v" will now be a array of all first names. The array will/can be multi-dimensional if your query has multiple columns.

Comment: You would need to move the recordset to the end, and then back again to fill the array successfully, otherwise you will only get the first row using  
`rstData.MoveLast 
rstData.MoveFirst`

Comment: MSDN Docs: [Recordset.GetRows Method (DAO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff194427.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple example of how you could take the contents of a column in a table and dynamically add it to the array:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub loadIntoArray()

Dim rstTableName As DAO.Recordset   'Your table
Dim myArray() As String             'Your dynamic array
Dim intArraySize As Integer         'The size of your array
Dim iCounter As Integer             'Index of the array

'Open your table
Set rstTableName = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table1")

If Not rstTableName.EOF Then

    rstTableName.MoveFirst   'Ensure we begin on the first row

    'The size of the array should be equal to the number of rows in the table
    intArraySize = rstTableName.RecordCount - 1
    iCounter = 0
    ReDim myArray(intArraySize) 'Need to size the array

    Do Until rstTableName.EOF

        myArray(iCounter) = rstTableName.Fields("Field1")
        Debug.Print "Item: "; iCounter & " " & myArray(iCounter)

        iCounter = iCounter + 1
        rstTableName.MoveNext
    Loop

End If

If IsObject(rstTableName) Then Set rstTableName = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Albert's solution above will work, but you would need to move the recordset to the end and then back again to fill the array fully, otherwise you will only get the first row. Use `MoveLast` and `MoveFirst` for this.

```
Dim rstData    As DAO.Recordset
Dim v          As Variant

Set rstData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select FirstName from FaxBook3")
rstData.MoveLast
rstData.MoveFirst  
v = rstData.GetRows(rstData.RecordCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is using the following statements:
Spanish (español): Otra forma de hacerlo es de la siguiente manera:

CLIENTSLIST table: One column

Me.ListFileContent.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"

Me.ListFileContent.RowSource = "CLIENTSLIST"

Note: The ListBox show up all data.