# How do I change a looping input to one that accepts a list or table input from access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am attempting update routinely used code designed by a previous employee to make it more efficient.

The code works fine but prompts the user to input a "PlateID" with every loop. This was developed when a worker would only have one or two plates to input , now we have people inputting upwards of 30-40, which is killing productivity (not only a huge risk for user error).

What I would like to is instead of querying the user for PlateID each time, instead take a list input or even just take the list from a table.

The purpose of this code is to taken Plate information we receive from lab equipment and transform it into a format we can use in-lab.

I have tried changing the qrySamplesOnPlates query to have a criteria that is a list but it seems to get overwritten by the code, even if I comment out the input box. I know this is probably really easy its just doing my head in.

```
    Sub PCRSplit(OutputLoc As String)


    Dim objConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim objCmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim LabID As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tblRst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim PlateID As Integer
    Dim Rst1 As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim AryWellLetter, AryLayoutFullPlate, AryLayoutWell, SampleID, WellNumber, RowNumber, WellLetter
    Dim varAnswer As Variant
    Dim exRst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim ProjectName As String
    Dim ExperimentName As String
    Dim Manifest As String
    Dim manRst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ControlPos As String
    Dim Counter As Integer


        If objConn = "" Then
            Set objConn = GetNewConnection
            objCmd.ActiveConnection = objConn
        End If

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    'delete everything out of the table that sample ID's get written to
    objCmd.CommandText = "qrySamplesOnPlatesDELETE"
    objCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    objCmd.Parameters.Refresh
    objCmd.Execute

    'LabID is a criteria for the query that pulls out plate information
    LabID = InputBox("Enter Lab")

    'open the table that sample ID's get written to
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set tblRst = db.OpenRecordset("SamplesOnPlates")

    Do

    'PlateID is a criteria for the query that pulls out plate information
    PlateID = InputBox("Enter Plate")

    'run the query to pull download pre-formatted plate information and assign it to the variable Rst1
    objCmd.CommandText = "qrySamplesOnPlates"
    objCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    objCmd.Parameters.Refresh
    Set Rst1 = objCmd.Execute(, Array(LabID, PlateID))

    'whole bunch of data transformation lines (dont worry about this)
    For i = 1 To 96
    AryWellLetter = Array("PlaceHolder", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F","G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P")
    AryLayoutFullPlate = Split(Rst1.Fields("Layout").Value, "][")
    AryLayoutWell = Split(AryLayoutFullPlate(i), ",")
    SampleID = AryLayoutWell(2)
    ControlPos = AryLayoutWell(3)
    If Len(AryLayoutWell(1)) = 1 Then WellNumber = "0" & AryLayoutWell(1) Else WellNumber = AryLayoutWell(1)
    RowNumber = AryLayoutWell(0)
    WellLetter = AryWellLetter(RowNumber)
    With tblRst
    .AddNew
    .Fields("SampleID") = SampleID
    .Fields("Well") = WellLetter & WellNumber
    .Fields("PlateID") = PlateID
    .Fields("LabID") = LabID
    .Fields("ControlPos") = ControlPos
    .Update

    End With

    Next

    'this will loop through the above code and continue to add new plates to the SamplesOnPlates table until the user clicks No button

    varAnswer = MsgBox("Do you want to enter another plate?", vbYesNo)

    Loop Until varAnswer = 7

    tblRst.Close

    'more transformation after this that isnt relevant
```

PlateID = InputBox("Enter Plate") is the key area in looking to change

Comment: Use a table and a form to input the new plates. Then modify your query to join this table and append all plates in one go. When done, delete the new plates or mark them as registered.

Comment: Thanks thats one method that would work. For anyone else reading this, I used this method detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284063/how-can-i-copy-data-from-an-access-table-to-an-array-in-vba) by Eddie/Simple Sandman. I essentially copied it word for word and inserted my transformation and the appending code into the "Do Until" loop which just loops through the table.