# Copy Table to Array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access

I am querying a table, creating a temp table then trying to add values from it to an array but I am having an issue.

It is creating a multi-dimensional array, even though I am only querying one column.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
Dim strTable As String: strTable = "tblTemp"

Dim strSQL As String: strSQL = "Select * Into " & strTable & " FROM tblBranches " & _
                        "Where EffBranch = '" & strBranch & "'"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

Dim rstData As DAO.Recordset: Set rstData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select BranchAbb From " & strTable)
rstData.MoveLast
rstData.MoveFirst
Dim aFN As Variant: aFN = rstData.GetRows(rstData.RecordCount)
```

This is the link I found the code for copying a table to an array:
[How Can I Copy Data From an Access Table to An array In VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284063/how-can-i-copy-data-from-an-access-table-to-an-array-in-vba)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `GetRows` always returns a 2D array.  If you want a 1D array then you'll need to write a loop to do the conversion

Comment: Or include another field in the SQL.